# Mongo crash after 2 seconds of starting

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.0

My `mongod` service crashes within 2-5 seconds of starting. I don't understand why.

Here are the `systemctl` logs:

> **systemctl status mongod.service**

```
mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-05-05 11:43:57 UTC; 4min 40s ago
Process: 7597 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS run (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 7601 (code=exited, status=14)

May 05 11:43:52 database13.choozon.net systemd[1]: Starting High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database...
May 05 11:43:52 database13.choozon.net mongod[7597]: warning: bind_ip of 0.0.0.0 is unnecessary; listens on all ips by default
May 05 11:43:52 database13.choozon.net mongod[7597]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
May 05 11:43:52 database13.choozon.net mongod[7597]: forked process: 7601
May 05 11:43:54 database13.choozon.net systemd[1]: Started High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.
May 05 11:43:57 database13.choozon.net systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=14/n/a
May 05 11:43:57 database13.choozon.net systemd[1]: mongod.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 05 11:43:57 database13.choozon.net systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

So far I have:

- checked permissions (everything looks good)
- checked the service
- tried deleting `mongo.lock`

`mongod` appears to start without any errors, but then fails after a couple of seconds.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you check the disk space available in dbpath? Also, good to check memory

Comment: Have you checked the `mongod` log for errors? What are your specific versions for MongoDB and O/S, and how did you install MongoDB?

Comment: The `systemctl` output indicates `(code=exited, status=14)` as a shutdown reason, which means an [unrecoverable error](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/exit-codes/#14) was encountered. There should be more detailed information in your `mongod` log.

Answer (score -1):

Search for `mongod.lock` and remove it and restart the service.

1. Find out the Mongo data path `cat /etc/mongod.conf | grep dbPath`
2. Look for `mongod.lock` file in it.
3. If its there then delete the file and restart the server.